# Edit multiple orgmode-files in same buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have multiple (possibly a few dozen) small *.org-documents within a nested folder structure.

Is there a way to **manipulate all these documents in a single orgmode buffer** and **have the changes applied to the individual files**?

*[I want to use org-files to keep my notes on various research papers. But it would be nice to keep them in individual files next to the pdfs, so I can share these notes easily.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to now, an Emacs buffer is linked to zero or one file, never more.

A workaround would be to make a LP (Literate Programming) Org document where you tangle individual Org snippets to different files.  Though, I'm not sure it's that easier... (because Org syntax would have to be escaped, and so on).